# Mysql full text search exact phrase problem

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Using full text search in mysql I'd like to have exact phrase:

```
"romantic dinner" to be found.
```

But I also would like each of the words could have synonyms like:

"romantic dinners" to be found for example (our language has great problem where every word has 8 endings like)...

I tried:

```
+"romantic (dinner dinners)" and
"romantic +(dinner dinners)"
```

but nothing seems to get results... Is it possible to make some logical OR inside exact search?

UPDATE: TO make it one sentance question: Is there a way to put some logical operators in exact match ("") in full text search?

Answer (score 0):

It will only partially your problem, but there is a [soundex()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function in mysql which transform the given string to a soundex representation. Similars string should have the same soundex representation so it's maybe a start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, but I don't use English language so this is no use to me. I am also making a search engline through my site so I use boolean full text search.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field_name FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(field_name) AGAINST('romantic* dinner*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)...
```

definitely you can use + and - to further refining your results
reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: yes, but this is not full text search... And problem is romantic in my langauge also users like 8 different endigns so I'd have to use 8*8 = 64 likes to find all :-(

Comment: This would also find "dinner romantic" and problem to us is that we don't use like dinners for plural but a different word :-(

Answer (score 0):

If '"roman* dinn*" doesn't work for you, it might be time to look into something like Solr: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ which will allow for more sophisticated searches, and might already have a stemmer for your language.

Comment: roma* dinn* isn't good as I can not know where to break the word... I use IIS7.0 so Solr would not work.

Comment: There's a .net port for Lucene at [link](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) and Lucene/Solr has lots of language-handling code, and there are places in the indexing and query pipelines to plug in your own code.